# How can i use phonegap camera api and status bar notification

Tags: cordova

How can i use phonegap camera api and status bar notification for both android and iOS. It will be best for me if anybody can provide url with example.

Answer (score 1):

1. You first need to install Cordova

   **npm install -g cordova**
2. Create an App

   **cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld**
3. Once it has generate the App, go inside the folder

   **cd hello**
4. Now add your desired environments/platforms

   **cordova platform add ios**

   **cordova platform add android**
5. To add a plugin ( for Camera)

   **cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera**

   for notifications

   **cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.dialogs**
6. To build App (all platforms altogether)

   **cordova build**
7. To test on emulator

   **cordova emulate android**
8. to test on device

   **cordova run android**

for more info: [Cordova CLI](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.6.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface)

**How to add plugins in PhoneGap Build**

In order to use a plugin in PhoneGap App that you like to build via PhoneGap Build service then you have to add those plugin details in the **config.xml** file as shown below.

for example:

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>

<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera"  />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation"  />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs"  />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device"  />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information"  />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console"  />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser"  />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information"  />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen"  />
```

Good Tutorial: [Developing a PhoneGap App](http://coenraets.org/blog/phonegap-tutorial/)

Comment: I am using ->   phonegap create myapp . Its necessary to use cordova CLI for plugins because i am able to do everything except plugins.

Comment: Okay, I have modified my reply if this is okay then mark the question otherwise let me know.